# Setting a note on edited cell by active user

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

**Hi, everyone. Could anyone make me a script for google sheet to set a note on edited cell by active user?**

```
// NOTE FUNCTION - START //

function onEdit(e){

  let range = e.range; //get the range of edited cell  
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  yil = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "dd-MM-yyyy");
  vaqt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "HH:mm");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let row = range.getRow(); //get the row
  let note_range = `B${row}`; //set note range using row B

  ss.getRange(note_range).setNote(yil + " yil " + vaqt + " da " + getCurrentUserEmail() + " tomonidan o'zgartirilgan."); //set note

}


// NOTE FUNCTION - END //


// Get User Email //

function getCurrentUserEmail(){
  var email=Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log(email);
}
```

[image]

Comment: That is awful wording for a Stack Overflow question. While grammatically, this has a question statement. We are looking for practical, detailed problems programmers face, not requests like this. Please check out [ask] and [edit] the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Upon trying your code, it is working as intended. It is setting note on the edited row in `column B`. The reason why you are getting `undefined` is because you are just using `logger.log` instead of `return` to catch the value on the onEdit function:

```
  Logger.log(email);
```

Change it to `return email;` instead.

Your modified code should look like this:

```
function onEdit(e){

 let range = e.range; //get the range of edited cell 
 var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
 yil = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "dd-MM-yyyy");
 vaqt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "HH:mm");
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 let row = range.getRow(); //get the row
 let note_range = `B${row}`; //set note range using row B

 ss.getRange(note_range).setNote(yil + " yil " + vaqt + " da " + getCurrentUserEmail() + " tomonidan o'zgartirilgan."); //set note

}


// NOTE FUNCTION - END //

function getCurrentUserEmail(){
 var email=Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
 return email;
}
```

**Result:**
[image]

[image]

*Please note:*

> Note: the script only works when the owner of the script belongs to
> the same Google Workspace domain as the active user. It does not work
> for users that are using a @gmail.com account.

Reference: [Script to return Users Name on Edit of Cell](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/110207491/?fbclid=IwAR3Kw5k5Ia9VHtpHPfxtBbZgYFeB_yqOvtt-aC9b8buwomT29qUUIhyP-iM)

Comment: Tried your code, but shows blank

Comment: I have edited my answer to show the results I got. can you elaborate the  behavior on your end? @NodirbekKhajiev

Comment: Why on me it's not working, i've edited question

Comment: It's working only on owner. But other users can't

Comment: I have edited my answer, kindly refer to the link I have shared. It states that: `Note: the script only works when the owner of the script belongs to the same Google Workspace domain as the active user. It does not work for users that are using a @gmail.com account.`

Comment: Hope this helps and clear out your concern

Comment: Ok. Can I set editor mail to special cell when user edits value of cell?

Comment: Thank you for replying and I hope I answered your concern. I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is a new concern, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as a new question by including the detailed information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as a new question, users including me can think of it. @NodirbekKhajiev

Answer (score -1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const excl = ["Sheet10", "Sheet11", "Sheet12"]; //Excluded sheets
  const idx = excl.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if (!~idx) {
    let message="This is the message"
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).setNote(`Date/Time:${new Date()},User:${Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()},${message}`);
  }
}
```

The note will be on all edits to all non excluded sheets

Comment: Thanks for code, but It's not showing other user's email

Comment: Yes.  Your are not always guaranteed to be able to [access other users emails](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user#detailed-documentation).